# How do you say "to have a good time"?

Tags: phrase-requests

How do you say that you are having/had a pleasing moment? Is there a common expression for this?

Answer (score 7):

Estas multaj eblaj esprimoj:

- Mi havas agrablan tempon
- Mi fartas bone tie ĉi
- Mi ĝuas la restadon tie ĉi
- Mi vere kontentas nun

Ĉio dependas de la kunteksto, laŭ mi.

Answer (score 4):

La kurso de Duolingo tradukas tion per:

> *amuziĝi*